# extShutdownHook Spring boot JAR file AWS EC2 deployment error

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am now making Spring boot based Web project.

When using AWS EC2 ubuntu for deployment, unsolved error came out and I want to share.

Project stack: Spring boot + AWS (EC2, S3, RDS(MariaDB))
Deployment is run by ubuntu with Spring boot JAR file.
`java -jar *.jar`

The problem is whenever I start application by JAR file, the server immediately stops with this log. I thought it is because of WebSocketConfig.java for Chat messaging function, but even I added `Threadpoooltaskschedule` and `STOMP setAllowedOrigins`, symtoms still exists.
Exhausted with solving by own, I need some help from you guys.

`WebSocketConfig.java`

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsocketBrokerConfig.class);

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

    //for subscribe prefix
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/user");
    //for publish prefix
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    //user destination provides ability to have unique user queue
    //registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    
    registry.addEndpoint("/broadcast")
        .setAllowedOrigins("http://ec2....amazonaws.com")   
        .withSockJS()
        .setHeartbeatTime(60_000);
}
```

````
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)

2021-03-03 00:44:34.278  INFO 5898 --- [           main] com.example.salle.SalleApplication       : Starting SalleApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_282 on ip-172-31-46-33 with PID 5898 (/home/ubuntu/salle/salle/target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by ubuntu in /home/ubuntu/salle/salle)
2021-03-03 00:44:34.283  INFO 5898 --- [           main] com.example.salle.SalleApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-03 00:44:36.435  INFO 5898 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-03-03 00:44:36.489  INFO 5898 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-03-03 00:44:38.298  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-03-03 00:44:38.330  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-03 00:44:38.330  INFO 5898 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-03-03 00:44:39.363  INFO 5898 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2021-03-03 00:44:39.969  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-03 00:44:39.969  INFO 5898 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5536 ms
2021-03-03 00:44:41.016  INFO 5898 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-03 00:44:41.247  INFO 5898 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-03-03 00:44:41.408  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-03-03 00:44:41.600  INFO 5898 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final
2021-03-03 00:44:41.900  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-03-03 00:44:42.217  INFO 5898 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
2021-03-03 00:44:43.125  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
ct.MariaDB103Dialect
2021-03-03 00:44:43.155  INFO 5898 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-03-03 00:44:45.786  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2021-03-03 00:44:45.860  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2021-03-03 00:44:46.023  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2021-03-03 00:44:46.025  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2021-03-03 00:44:46.035  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'brokerChannelExecutor'
2021-03-03 00:44:46.140  WARN 5898 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-03-03 00:44:47.221  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-03-03 00:44:47.227  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2021-03-03 00:44:47.227  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [DefaultSubscriptionRegistry[cache[0 destination(s)], registry[0 sessions]]]]
2021-03-03 00:44:47.233  INFO 5898 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
2021-03-03 00:44:47.252  INFO 5898 --- [           main] com.example.salle.SalleApplication       : Started SalleApplication in 14.288 seconds (JVM running for 15.469)
2021-03-03 00:45:00.256  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Stopping...
2021-03-03 00:45:00.258  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=false, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [DefaultSubscriptionRegistry[cache[0 destination(s)], registry[0 sessions]]]]
2021-03-03 00:45:00.258  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Stopped.
2021-03-03 00:45:00.284  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'brokerChannelExecutor'
2021-03-03 00:45:00.284  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2021-03-03 00:45:00.284  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2021-03-03 00:45:00.284  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2021-03-03 00:45:00.296  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-03-03 00:45:00.299  INFO 5898 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...```
````

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to put a Spring BOOT app on an EC2 instance is to use Elastic Beanstalk. Read this AWS doc for more details - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: It is not direct solution for an error, but thank you for reminding

Comment: See if you can deploy your Spring app by following those instructions.

Comment: I read it through your link, but I figured out in advance. It was a silly mistake of mine. As I used nohup command to run JAR file on background process(so I can use terminal to work other things). But the nohup syntax remains I could not go back to terminal. So I pressed Ctrl+c to terminate foreground process which I though nohup, but it killed JAR file deployment. haha.... Have a nice day